# Android Studio IDE Layout, can't have full length side panel with bottom panel

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, ide

I want to change my Android Studio Layout like in the picture, I tried "Move to: Bottom Left" on the Logcat, but it became so narrow.

I want to have a full-length Emulator view and a Terminal view that is high enough to see, but not wide enough to obstruct the Emulator view.

Can anyone please guide a returning developer on this new UI change?

[image: A picture showing how it is, and in red/yellow how I want it]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to

- File -> Settings
- Appearance and behaviour -> Appearance
- Scroll bottom and Check Widescreen tool window layout